# Template won't append, but other things will

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am really stumped by this one. I have a template which contains data. I alert the variable containing this rendered template to prove it contains the data. I have tried using html() innerHTML() and others to then convert it before appending it. Using identical jquery syntax,  I am able to append a div exactly as I desire, except with different contents.

```
   success: function (data) {
        if (data['success'] == 1) {

            $.get('templates/PostReply.mustache', function(file){

                var newPostArray={"reply_body":bodyText,
                    "replier_username": "<?php echo $sess_username; ?>",
                    "replier_profimg0": '<?php echo $sess_profimg0; ?>'
                };
                var html = Mustache.render(file, newPostArray);
                $('#new-posts-container').append(html);

                alert(html);

                $(form).closest('#reply-divy').nextAll('#new-posts-container').append('<div>hello</div>');
                //this works
                $(form).closest('#reply-divy').nextAll('#new-posts-container').append(html); 
                // this does not work

                e.preventDefault();
            }); 
        // You could also use the data['message'] that got sent back here.
        } 
    },
```

So for some reason, the contents are unable to append. I am not receiving any errors.

This is what html looks like in an alert:

```
<div class="reply-div">
    <div class="pull-left feed-entity-side-img">
        <a href="profilepage.php?username=cb_snn">
            <img src="photos&#x2F;user_photos&#x2F;public&#x2F;2015&#x2F;02&#x2F;12&#x2F;04&#x2F;1ded2487680.jpg" alt="User" class="media-object no-padding reply-side-img"/>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="media-body" style="padding-bottom:5px;">
        <span class="pull-right" style=""> </span>

        <a href="profilepage.php?username=cb_snn"><span ><b>co_byrne</b></span></a>
        <p> dgsadgasdgasdgasdgasdgasdgs
        </p>                                                        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are the contents of html? Is it a string? an object?

Comment: hey, sorry, fell asleep! seems to be a string.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: what is the value of `html` If you replace it with just a string like `"test"` it should work fine. So something is weird with your value of `html`

Comment: yeah, that appended fine.

Comment: I will show what 'html' looks like in the alert (in an edit above)

Comment: Hmm, I just tested it and it worked fine for me. I'm pulling at strings here but can you tell me what the result of alert(typeof html) is?

Comment: string. i think part of the problem is I cannot seem to run innerHTML on it because it's not in the DOM yet.  does that make sense?

Comment: oh man. I am so dumb. I figured it out. This is part of a comment section, and the class on the template is initially set to display:none. When I toggled the vis of the comments, I expected this to toggle as well, but I had put it in another div and not controlled by the toggle. Thank you SO much for the help. Truly appreciated.

Comment: Not a problem, glad you got it worked out :)